# dcast function with binary values and NA

Tags: r

I want to change column in my data.table with dcast but i don't want when it's binary values (0/1) or when isn't in levels

for example this data.table :

```
dt1 <- data.table::data.table("ID" = 1:4,'Col0' = c(1, 0, 1, 0),'Col1' = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'a'),'Col2' = (letters[20:23]),'Col3' = factor(c("a", "b", NA, "a"),levels = c("a", "b", "c")))
```

I add ID before for try dcast but we can move this value

I tried this but like I discribe before we have problem with levels and binary.

```
res = data.table::dcast(data.table::melt(dt1, id.vars='ID'), ID ~ variable + value, fun = length)
```

I tried to have this result.

```
result <- data.table::data.table('Col0' =  c(1, 0, 1, 0),'Col1_a' = c(1, 0, 0, 1),'Col1_b' = c(0, 1, 0, 0),'Col1_c' = c(0, 0, 1, 0),'Col2_t' = c(1, 0, 0, 0),'Col2_u' = c(0, 1, 0, 0),'Col2_v' = c(0, 0, 1, 0),'Col2_w' = c(0, 0, 0, 1), 'Col3_a' = c(1, 0, NA, 1),'Col3_b' = c(0, 1, NA, 0))
```

Comment: You can start with `dummies::dummy.data.frame(dt1, names = colnames(dt1)[!sapply(dt1, is.numeric)],
                          sep = "_")` or `fastDummies::dummy_cols(dt1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some alternatives:

**1) model.matrix** Function `mm` defines a model matrix based on column `nm` adding NA as a level.  Apply that to each column except `ID` and remove those columns that are either all zero or have `NA` in their name.

```
mm <- function(nm) model.matrix(~.-1, setNames(list(addNA(dt1[[nm]])), nm))
res <- do.call("cbind", lapply(names(dt1)[-1], mm))
res[, colSums(res) > 0 & !grepl("NA", colnames(res)) ]
```

giving:

```
  Col00 Col01 Col1a Col1b Col1c Col2t Col2u Col2v Col2w Col3a Col3b
1     0     1     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0
2     1     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     0     0     1
3     0     1     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     0     0
4     1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1     1     0
```

**2) melt/dcast** Using `melt` and `dcast` from data.table convert each column to factor and at the end remove columns whose name includes `NA`.

```
m <- melt(replace(dt1, TRUE, lapply(dt1, factor)), id.vars='ID')
res = dcast(m, ID ~ variable + value, fun = length)
subset(res, select = !grepl("NA", colnames(res)) )[, -1]
```

giving:

```
   Col0_0 Col0_1 Col1_a Col1_b Col1_c Col2_t Col2_u Col2_v Col2_w Col3_a Col3_b
1:      0      1      1      0      0      1      0      0      0      1      0
2:      1      0      0      1      0      0      1      0      0      0      1
3:      0      1      0      0      1      0      0      1      0      0      0
4:      1      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      1      1      0
```

Comment: Thanks i cross your 2 method to have my result